# In C++, does it make sense to use a function with std::optional<T> parameter, to denote optional parameters?

Tags: c++, option-type

I know that one can implement functions with optional parameters like so:

```
int someFunction(int A, int B = -1) {
   if (B != -1) {
       ... // If B given then do something
   } else { 
       ... // If B not given then do something else
   }
}
```

However, I'd lake to take advantage of std::optional as recommended by a coworker. Here's what I'm trying to do but I'm getting errors:

```
int some Function(int A, std::optional<int> B) {
    if (B.has_value()) {
        ... // If B given then do something
    } else { 
        ... // If B not given then do something else
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the first approach, I can call the function like so `someFunction(5)` and C++ will realize I've opted not to use the optional parameter. But in the second aproach calling `someFunction(5)` in the same way will produce the error `too few arguments to function call`.

I want to be able to call the function without including the optional argument with the second approach, is this possible/recommended?

Comment: an optional is typically to represent the presence/absence of a value (especially as a return), whereas _default parameters_ are what you're using in the first case. They're completely separate concepts in that regard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use it in the way you intend here, I believe you'd need to specify a default value of `std::nullopt`:

```
int some Function(int A, std::optional<int> B = std::nullopt) {
    if (B.has_value()) {
        ... // If B given then do something
    } else { 
        ... // If B not given then do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really make sense; the normal solution would be an additional overload `int some Function(int A)`.

Comment: Could you explain why it doesn't make sense? It seems to me using `std::optional<int> B = std::nullopt` is more "clean" as opposed to using `int B = -1` since the function can still be called with `-1` and the function will perform as if the optional parameter was not used.

Comment: @Minyc510 — the answer is suggesting two overloads: `int someFunction(int a)` and `int someFunction(int a, int b)`.

Comment: @Minyc510: You don't have a default for `B` anymore. If `Function` is called with one argument, the other overload is selected and that doesn't even have a `B` argument.

Comment: I see. In my particular case, that would require some code duplication, so I've opted for the accepted answer which leads to cleaner code. Again, at least for my case.